# Proxy configuration problem with Glassfish and GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have Geoserver running on 8080 and Glassfish on 9999.So for wfs-t i had to use some proxy script.But at the response part of firebug i got following code:

http://localhost:9999/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">

Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@eba9b0